# Derivation of Gravitational Lensing in Schutz's, "A First course in General Relativity" textbook

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, calculus, approximations, gravitational-lensing

On page 310 of the third edition of the textbook, Schutz writes:

> Suppose now we assume $M u \ll 1$ but is not entirely negligible. Then if we define
> $$
> y:=u(1-M u), \qquad u=y(1+M y)+\mathrm{O}\left(M^2 u^2\right)\, .\tag{11.52}
> $$

My question is how to derive the second relation. I can see if one starts with a  first approximation of $y=u$, then one can write $y\approx u(1-My)$ and then get the result $u\approx y(1+My)$ by using $1/(1-My)\approx 1+My$. But I was wondering if there is a more formal way of doing this derivation.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's essentially it. If you want to be more precise, you can define $U\equiv Mu$ and $Y\equiv My$. Then $$Y~=~f(U)~\equiv~U(1-U)~=~U+{\cal O}(U^2).\tag{1}$$ Now use [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula) for a [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series):
$$\begin{align}U~=~&f^{-1}(Y)\cr
~=~&Y+\underbrace{U^2}_{={\cal O}(Y^2)}\cr
~=~&Y+\underbrace{(Y+U^2)^2}_{=Y^2+{\cal O}(Y^3)}\cr
~=~&Y+\underbrace{(Y+(Y+U^2)^2)^2}_{=Y^2+2Y^3+{\cal O}(Y^4)}\cr
~=~&\ldots.\end{align}\tag{2}$$
The [fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) (2) is a rather general perturbative technique. In OP's specific case, one can also just [expand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series%5B%281-Sqrt%5B1-4Y%5D%29%2F2%2C%7BY%2C0%2C5%7D%5D) the relevant solution to the quadratic equation (1),
$$\begin{align}U~=~&\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4Y}}{2}\cr
~=~&Y+Y^2+2Y^3+5Y^4+14Y^5+42Y^6+{\cal O}(Y^7). \end{align}\tag{3} $$

Comment: Thanks, but I fin this link a little easier to follow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: I don't quite understand your Eq. (2). I think it should be $U=Y+Y^2+O(Y^3)$.

Comment: $\uparrow$ It is.

Comment: Thanks, I can also see how a standard Taylor series expansion of the Eq. (3) you added leads to $U=Y+Y^2+O[Y^3]$. It also makes sense to me that $O[Y^3]$ can be replaced with $O[U^2]$, which then matches the solution given in the textbook.

Comment: On second thoughts, isn't O[Y^3]=O[U^3]?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: That means that there is a mistake in the textbook, which appears both in Eq. (11.52) and (11.53).